# Representing planar graphs / GIS topology: ArcObjects vs. CGAL arrangements

Tags: c++, gis, arcobjects, cgal, topology

I need to represent a planar graph structure, i.e., a division of part of the plane into polygons so that I can easily find a polygon's neighbors etc (like on a map). What is the best library to use? ArcObjects? CGAL (2D arrangements)? Anything else?

I use C++ under Windows.

Comment: Finally settled on CGAL.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in speed or reliability, stay away from ArcObjects. ArcMap is a neat application, and there's good reasons to write plug-ins for it. But ArcObjects is not a good programming library for general purpose GIS use.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at QGIS and see what they use under the hoods.

You could also look at GEOS. It might have some of the stuff you need

http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/

Actually - after looking at it a bit I think it could definitely suit your needs.